# T-test after running sentiment analysis

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, t-test

I am trying to run a t-test after doing the sentiment analysis.
I did the sentiment analysis, and grouped my data into two parts:

```
library(textdata)
afinn_dictionary <- get_sentiments("afinn")

news_tokenized <- full_data %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, full_article, to_lower = TRUE)
head(news_tokenized$word, 10) 
full_data$full_article[2]

word_counts_senti <- news_tokenized %>% 
  inner_join(afinn_dictionary)

head(word_counts_senti)

news_senti <- word_counts_senti %>% 
  group_by(partisan_media) %>% #group by partisan media
  summarize(sentiment = sum(value))

head(news_senti) 
#as a result, I got: c(1): -13194, c(2): -12321. Both group 1 and 2 were negative, but group 1's stories tend to use more negative words (have greater negative sentiment).
table(full_data$partisan_media) #there are 1866 articles in group 1 and 2174 articles in group 2
```

I am trying to see if the differences between groups 1 and 2 (two groups of partisan media) are statistically different by running a t-test.
I'm using:

```
g1_senti = rnorm(1866, mean = -7.07074, sd = ) #group1
g2_senti = rnorm(2174, mean = -5.667433, sd = ) #group2
t.test(g1_senti, g2_senti)
```

The means are from "sentiment score of a group" divided by "number of articles of a group"
But I wasn't sure what should be entered inside the parenthesis for the sd. Does anyone have an idea about this?

I am adding my data set here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/uei2e3tajvi7wao/eight.csv/file

Comment: Why are you using rnorm?

Comment: I referred to https://statistics.berkeley.edu/computing/r-t-tests and just wanted to follow this instruction. Is it incorrect to use rnorm here?

Comment: rnorm creates randomly generated data. They use it to simulate some examples. If you're analyzing real data you just use the data you have. You don't need to simulate anything.

Comment: Could you provide a sample data of your using `dput(x)`?

Comment: I see--I will remove the rnorm function from my t-test. Thanks! This is a link to my data: https://www.mediafire.com/file/uei2e3tajvi7wao/eight.csv/file

Comment: I'm not sure if I am doing this correctly, but can I use: t.test(word_counts_senti$value ~ word_counts_senti$partisan_media) ? "word_counts_senti$value" represents the sentiment scores of each news articles and "word_counts_senti$partisan_media" is a grouping variable (that distinguishes each article into group 1 or 2)